# quotes appearing in result of a bat file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I try to do a batch process with some files and create an XML with the information gathered, but to create the string in the XML I'm forced to declare the var within quotes and those quotes appear later in the XML.

The bat file

---

```
cls
var mybar
set "mybar="
for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do call :concat %%i
echo "%mybar%" >mig.txt
copy inici.txt+mig.txt+final.txt prova2.txt
goto :eof

:concat
set "inici=<file indexFlag="False"> <name><![CDATA["
set "final=]]></name><folder><![CDATA[pdfs]]></folder></file>"
set "mybar=%mybar%%inici%%1%final%"
goto :eof
```

The resulting XML file

---

```
  <files>     "                              <= THESE QUOTES SHOULD NOT APPEAR
    <file indexFlag="False"> 
      <name>
        <![CDATA[K:\files\aaa.pdf]]>
      </name>
      <folder>
        <![CDATA[pdfs]]>
      </folder>
     </file> 
     <file indexFlag="False"> 
       <name>
         <![CDATA[K:\files\bbb.pdf]]>
       </name>
       <folder>
         <![CDATA[pdfs]]>
       </folder>
      </file>"                       <= THESE QUOTES SHOULD NOT APPEAR
   </files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line

```
echo "%mybar%" >mig.txt
```

you can strip quotes from a variable by using a `~` inside a `for` loop as follows:

```
(for %%a in ("%mybar%") do echo %%~a )> mig.txt
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. It add ~a to the result. Thanks anyway

Comment: Odd, it works on my machine. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set mybar') DO IF "%%a"=="mybar" >mig.txt ECHO(%%b
```

This should solve your problem - but obviously not reformat the XML produced.

The output of `set` would be `mybar=<file index...</file>`; delimiter of `=` would apply `mybar` to `%%a` and `<file index...</file>` to `%%b`

You would need to filter the output as shown to restrict the `ECHO`ing to ``` "%%a"=="mybar"`` in case ```mybar1`or any other variable beginning`mybar` is set

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "openFile=<file indexFlag="False"> <name><![CDATA["
    set "closeFile=]]></name><folder><![CDATA[pdfs]]></folder></file>"

    (for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do (
        set "file=%openFile%%%~fi%closeFile%"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!file!
        endlocal
    )) > mig.txt

    copy inici.txt+mig.txt+final.txt prova2.txt
```

Comment: Wonderful! thanks a lot. You solved another mistake I saw later in the initial code, so double thanks.